# Apache2 Linux/debian - cannot run php-scripts

Tags: debian, apache-httpd

I just installed php and apache2 server from this tutorial

https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-latest-php-on-debian/

but I cannot run php-scripts - the server seems to be down since localhost in url wont work

According to the php.ini file engine is ON

```
 engine = On
```

Right now I cannot find which port the server is listening on in the ini-file but I guess its 80?

If write apache2 in the terminal it responds

```
apache2: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: No such file or directory
```

the path is not the same, on my system the pat is

```
/etc/apache2/mods-available/
```

and there are two files:

```
php7.4.conf
php7.4.load
```

So - how could I start the server or at the least get a grasp of whats wrong?

Comment: To check, which service is listning on which port run this command `sudo ss -tnpl`

Comment: ss -tulpn | grep -i httpd
or
ss -tulpn | grep -i apache2

Answer (score 0):

Question is did you run those two commands or not?

```
sudo systemctl disable --now apache2
sudo apt-get install nginx php7.4-fpm
```

First command disables apache2.
The second one installs nginx and php-fpm version 7.4
However the tutorial does not describe how to use virtual hosts, how to enable and disable service etc.

I recommend to use this tutorial: [Install PHP 7.4 on Debian 10](https://www.cloudbooklet.com/install-php-7-4-on-debian-10/)

Besides also additionally recommend to read and learn from my website: [Web server installation on mikr.us using MariaDB and MyISAM engine](https://sysadmin.info.pl/en/web-server-installation-on-mikr-us-using-mariadb-and-myisam-engineweb-server-installation-on-mikr-us-using-mariadb-and-myisam-engine/)

You will learn how to install and configure Apache , Virtual Host and maybe other things will be also interesting for you. It is a really full guide step by step for beginners. Enjoy. If you will have any questions do not hesitate to ask me.

Comment: thanks i'll look into this issue and may accept later :)

Comment: I did not run those commands. Usually have problems with systemctl

Comment: Something more bout the error? The =answer is very enigmatic.